# Admob iOS - My app show ads only on simulator and not on real device

Tags: ios, swift, admob

My swift app shows ads on simulator but when I connect my iPad or another real device, there's no ad on the app and the debugger error is :

> adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: Request Error: No ad to show.

But on the Xcode simulator all is fine. This is my code :

```
    let request = GADRequest()
    banner.adUnitID = "/* My Secret Code */"
    banner.rootViewController = self
    banner.delegate = self
    banner.load(request)
```

And in AppDelegate.swift :

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "/* My Secret Code */")
```

What can I do?

Comment: is limit Ad tracking on in your device  > ios 10 above?

Comment: No, I search and it isn’t active

Comment: try solution provided here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439912/google-admob-live-ads-not-showing-in-ios-11-on-real-device?noredirect=1#comment83786145_47439912

Comment: My device is supported . So I don't understand . Should I ask directly to AdMob service?

Comment: I've tried to add Test Banner and all is fine.
So, I think the problem is Server Side . Some advice?

Comment: if you have exhausted above solutions provided... try connecting with admob support team